# JQuery buttons lock for some time

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I have some buttons on an HTML webpage.

After one being clicked I need the rest to be disabled for 1 min. How can I do this?

I also need to show a timer for the minute. How can I do it?

Comment: Easy, Html has a Disabled property you can add to the element you want using jquery or javascript. just build a timer function that will add this property at the beginning and it will removed it after one minute.

Comment: I know the algorythm but I need to see the code of it

Comment: Please provide at least a some html and effort that you have put in. There are plenty of examples out there to disable things. Did you attempt anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//start jquery..
$(function(){

//get the the click of the button

 $("#button").click(function(){
   //disabled class toggle
   $(".toggle").prop('disabled', true);

  //enabled after 1 minute
  setTimeout( function(){ 

    //here you enabled all the html of class toggle.
   $(".toggle").prop('disabled', false);

  }
 , 60000 );

 });

});
```

any input of class toggle will be affected `<button class="toggle"></button>`

ps. This code is un-tested.